# How do I attatch my fence gate hinges

Tags: fence, hinges

I have these hinges

[image: fence hinge]

And I want to attach it to my fence but it the holes will miss the cross board.

[image: fence]

The bolts they gave me aren't long enough to reach the post.

Should I just get longer bolts and screw it into the post or do I need to attach another cross board for them to attach to?

Answer (score 2):

## Use one screw-in lag bolt per hinge that can penetrate to the post for at least one bolt hole

You're wise to realize this now. I learned this one the hard way. Had someone build a gate for me and used the maybe 1.5" bolts that came with it. Over time, the weight of the gate pulled the 2x4 away from the post. I have a drive-in lag bolt there now, but you'll be far better off if you lag bolt it now rather than later.

Comment: Since two is better than one, maybe add a wooden block below the cross board, same width as the cross board, same depth as the post to the left, which supports the second screw.

Comment: Where can I get one that size (measured 1.25")?  The local Lowe's doesn't carry it only 2 by X sizes. Would I have to go to a fence store?

Comment: [This lag bolt](https://spax.us/products/powerlags/hex-washer-head-hcr-powerlags) is what I used for mine (5" long). Bought it at Home Depot, but this or similar should be sold at Lowes as well.

Comment: I should clarify I meant where can I get a board that size